# DRF - a better way to write double nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, nested, serialization

I am building a todo app that can have comments posted on to the todo.
For that to work, I have made a writable double nested serializer. It works, but the update method I have written is difficult to understand, and so I am trying to make it more readable. Is there a better(or standard way) to write an update method for a double nested serializer?

I have read the docs for nested serializers in the official documents.   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Todo(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="todos",
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Todo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="comments",
    )
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

serializers.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = (
            'url',
            'title',
            'pub_date',
            'description',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'url',
            'pub_date',
        )


class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(required=False, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = (
            'url',
            'title',
            'pub_date',
            'description',
            'is_done',
            'comments'
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'url',
            'pub_date',
        )


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    todos = TodoSerializer(required=False, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'url',
            'email',
            'username',
            'todos',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'url',
            'email',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        todos = validated_data.pop('todos', None)
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if todos is not None:
            for todo in todos:
                comments = todo.pop('comments', None)
                Todo.objects.create(user=user, **todo)
                if comments is not None:
                    for comment in comments:
                        Comment.objects.create(todo=todo, **comment)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        todos_data = validated_data.pop('todos', None)
        todos = (instance.todos).all()
        todos = list(todos)
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.save()
        if todos_data is not None:
            for todo_data in todos_data:
                comments_data = todo_data.pop('comments')
                todo = todos.pop(0)
                comments = (todo.comments).all()
                comments = list(comments)

                todo.title = todo_data.get('title', todo.title)
                todo.description = todo_data.get('description', todo.description)
                todo.is_done = todo_data.get('is_done', todo.is_done)
                todo.save()
                if comments_data is not None:
                    for comment_data in comments_data:
                        comment = comments.pop(0)
                        comment.title = comment_data.get('title', comment.title)
                        comment.description = comment_data.get('description', comment.description)
                        comment.save()
        return instance
```

expected JSON

```
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/4/",
    "email": "api01@example.com",
    "username": "api01",
    "todos": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/1/",
            "title": "first todo1.1",
            "pub_date": "2019-07-04T12:40:56.799308+09:00",
            "description": "description for first todo1.1",
            "is_done": true,
            "comments": [
                {
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comment/1/",
                    "title": "first comment-1.1",
                    "pub_date": "2019-07-03T12:32:26.604598+09:00",
                    "description": "aaaaaaaaa-1.1"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comment/2/",
                    "title": "second comment-1.1",
                    "pub_date": "2019-07-03T12:56:22.906482+09:00",
                    "description": "bbbbbbbbbbb-1.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how you expect this to be used. So you are expecting that the user will create all his todos at the same time and each todo will already have a bunch of comments at the time of creation? That is very far from reality. In reality, you create each today separately and comments are gradually added to each todo. So your serializers are unnecessarily complex

Comment: Oh.. I guess I have misunderstood the way of using serializers. I thought that I had to combine all of them to use them in one page, such as when I want to load on to a page the todos from a specific user, and the comments posted on to the todo. Thank you!

Comment: You can always make multiple requests to get the data for a page. And also, you can decide to return all the todos and comments attached to them in the same request but create them separately. You can read about read_only and write_only fields

Comment: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested could be of use

Answer (score 1):

It should be the responsibility of respective serializer to create the model. So `TodoSerializer` should only create Todo object and `CommentSerializer` should create Comment object. Same for update

Also you dont need to call `Model.objects.create(**data)`. Serializer can do it by itself. All you need is to call `super().create(validated_data)` or `super().update(instance, validated_data)`.

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    comments = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'title',
            'pub_date',
            'description',
            'is_done',
            'comment',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data)
        todo = super().create(validated_data)
        comments = validated_data.pop('comments', [])
        for comment in comments:
            comment['todo'] = todo.id
            serializer = CommentSerializer(data=comment)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()


class AddBulkTodos(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    todos = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'url',
            'email',
            'username',
            'todos',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'url',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data)
        todos = validated_data.pop('todos', [])
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        for todo in todos:
            todo['user'] = user.id
            serializer = TodoSerializer(data=todo)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
```